# Looping over two variables?

Tags: r, loops, finance

Good Morning!

I have a quite large (panel) dataset containing daily stock return data for 289 companies over a period of 30 years. I addition, I also have data on the corresponding return on a market portfolio.

Now, my aim is to get a **yearly** beta measure for each stock. Thus, 289 distinct "beta-series" of length 30.

I am quite new to R but I believe the best way to archive this is to loop over the company **as well as** the year indicators.

```
  for (i in 1:length(unique(company), j in 1:length(unique(year))){
  data_ij <- data[which(data$company==i,data$year==j),]
  beta_ij <- lm(data_ij$RETURN ~ data_ij$MARKET)
}
```

However, this does not seem to work at all. Could someone please offer me some guidance? :)

/Alex

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (i in 1:length(unique(company)){
   for( j in 1:length(unique(year))){
  data_ij <- data[which(data$company==i,data$year==j),]
  beta_ij <- lm(data_ij$RETURN ~ data_ij$MARKET)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not nested loops,

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(company))) {
    for (j in 1:length(unique(year))) {
        ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
beta_series <- lapply(levels(data$company), 
                 function(x) lapply(unique(data$year), 
                               function(y) lm(RETURN ~ MARKET,
                               data = subset(data, company == x & year == y))))
```

You can use a nested `lapply()` call to first loop over the levels of your `company` variable (works with `unique(data$company)` if you have more levels than companies you want to analyse). Within this you loop over the unique years and call the `lm()` on a `subset` defined by your current iteration.